# Routing different modules with same paths

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, angular-router

After I decided to merge two Angular apps on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54871238/changing-top-level-routes-for-multiple-angular-apps-served-from-single-nginx-ser), I ran into another problem. Some routes on app1 and app2 have the same path.

Here is an example:

app.routing.ts (root):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'app1',
        loadChildren: './app1/app1.module#App1Module'
    },
    {
        path: 'app2',
        loadChildren: './app2/app2.module#App2Module'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

app1.routing.ts (App1):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'page1',
        component: ./app1page1/app1page1.module#App1Page1Module
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

app2.routing.ts (App2):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'page1',
        component: ./app2page1/app2page1.module#App2Page1Module
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

app1page1.routing.ts (App1 - Page1):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: App1Page1Component,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'subpage1',
                component: App1Subpage1Component
            }
        ]
    }
]

 @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

app2page1.routing.ts (App2 - Page1):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: App2Page1Component,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'subpage1',
                component: App2Subpage1Component
            }
        ]
    }
]

 @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

The problem is: when I navigate to e.g. www.mysite.com/app1/page1 I get redirected to /app2/page1 instead. How can I fix the routes without having to give everything a unique path?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I've modified the example to more accurately describe my situation and better reflect my app's structure. Basically, there are two layers of loadChilden. I noticed I'm actually not able to navigate to the lazy loaded children of app1 and app2 themselves (i.e. if I go to /app2/page1/subpage1 I'm redirected to /app1/page1/subpage1). By navigate, I mean both manually typing the URL in the browser and running router.navigate in the code.

Update 2: after restarting my app, I got an error during compilation:

```
ERROR in Duplicated path in loadChildren detected: "./page1/page1.module#Page1Module" is used in 2 loadChildren, but they point to different modules "(/src/app/app1/page1/page1.module.ts and "/src/app/app2/page1/page1.module.ts"). Webpack cannot distinguish on context and would fail to load the proper one.
```

Is the only solution renaming the module?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How do you navigate to that route?

Comment: Do you load your lazy loaded modules routing module with `forChild()` ?

Comment: @GCirs I added new information to the question to better reflect my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the routes. I realized some modules had the same name in both app1 and app2. So I renamed them.

But now instead of loading the wrong page, it threw a "module not found" error. Even after restarting the server, the error persisted. The solution was to include the full absolute path in loadChildren (e.g. src/app/app1...).

Answer (score 0):

Well it shouldn't get navigated to that one. Although try to attach

```
pathMatch: 'full'
```

means, that the whole URL path needs to match and is consumed by the route matching algorithm.